# Laravel collection filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

```
{
    {
        id: 125,
        apartments: [
            {
                floor: 28,
            },
            {
                floor: 29,
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 126,
        apartments: [
            {
                floor: 25,
            },
            {
                floor: 29,
            }
        ],
    },
    ....
}
```

It is sample collection data.

Now I want to `filter` this collection by `floor` attribute. For example, I want to get only `floor == 29`
I want to get all the data that including `floor == 29`.

How can I filter it?

Comment: What have you tried? Laravel `Collection` has a `filter` method; maybe use that? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter

Comment: can you add your eloquent query where you're getting these records?

Comment: The format looks weird. Can you show the actual array?

Comment: use `collection->pluck('apartments')->filter(function($array) use ($floor) {...})`

Comment: and I forgot about `->collapse()` between `pluck()` and `filter()`. `->pluck()->collapse()->filter()`